# Title of time travel story where a reporter is sent back to the Roman era?

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, novel

I'm looking for a novel or novelette written in the late 50's early 60's where a reporter is sent to investigate phenomena at some Indian mounds and a storm approaches and in the storm he is transported back to I believe the Roman era where he's a prisoner oarsman on a ship.

Comment: http://www.home.netspeed.com.au/reguli/fanro1.htm - One of these, possibly

Answer (score 3):

You may be thinking of *Lest Darkness Falls*; I don't remember the author. 
I remember reading it many years ago, the man was transported back in time to the Roman era and helped to defeat Rome's enemies. He was able to build a telegraph line to warn of attacks. He wanted to stop the Dark Ages from occurring; hence the Darkness in the title.
Hope this helps.

Comment: The story *you* are thinking of is *Lest Darkness Fall* by L. Sprague de Camp. Doesn't really fit the OP's description.

Comment: Actually, in LDF he *defeats* the Roman (East Roman) army trying to capture Italy from the Goths.